# Quitar opcion de eliminar

Tags: jquery

Estoy realizando un menú, pero quisiera quitar la opción de eliminar registro, para solo dejar la opción de editar, utilice 'actions', me pueden apoyar con alguna otra opcion.

La parte de mi código:

```
{name:'Editar', index:'Editar', width:60, resizable:true,  sortable:true,  align:'center', editable: false, formatter: "actions",
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true,
                            editOptions: {},
                            addOptions: {},

                        }  }
```

[image: Lo que quiero quitar]

Comment: ¿Qué librerías involucran el código que usas? La información me parece que es muy poca para poderte ayudar.

Comment: @rgmh si el span o elemento HTML que utlizas hace uso de clases solo ocultalo con `.miClase {display:none;}`